# TypeError inside the `scikit-optimize` package

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scikit-optimize

When I use `scikit-optimize` version 0.7.4 to optimize a `scikit-learn` 0.23 model:

```
    rf = BayesSearchCV(
        RandomForestClassifier(
            min_samples_leaf=0.01, oob_score=True
        ), {
            'n_estimators': Integer(30, 200),
            'max_depth': Integer(10, 150),
            'min_samples_split': Real(0.05, 0.3),
        }, n_iter=32
    )
```

When I run `rf.fit`, it says,

```
  File "C:\Users\cloudy\PyCharmProjects\clixove\venv\lib\site-packages\skopt\space\space.py", line 764, in rvs
    if sp_version < (0, 16):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Version' and 'tuple'
```

But when I simply use `RandomForestClassifier`, and fit it, the error doesn't occur.
So, how to avoid this problem? Thank you!

The full of traceback is as following.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cloudy/PyCharmProjects/clixove/BasicML/classifier.py", line 106, in <module>
    rf.fit(clf.data['X_train'], clf.data['Y_train'])
  File "C:\Users\cloudy\PyCharmProjects\clixove\venv\lib\site-packages\skopt\searchcv.py", line 678, in fit
    optim_result = self._step(
  File "C:\Users\cloudy\PyCharmProjects\clixove\venv\lib\site-packages\skopt\searchcv.py", line 552, in _step
    params = optimizer.ask(n_points=n_points)
  File "C:\Users\cloudy\PyCharmProjects\clixove\venv\lib\site-packages\skopt\optimizer\optimizer.py", line 360, in ask
    x = opt.ask()
  File "C:\Users\cloudy\PyCharmProjects\clixove\venv\lib\site-packages\skopt\optimizer\optimizer.py", line 332, in ask
    return self._ask()
  File "C:\Users\cloudy\PyCharmProjects\clixove\venv\lib\site-packages\skopt\optimizer\optimizer.py", line 398, in _ask
    return self.space.rvs(random_state=self.rng)[0]
  File "C:\Users\cloudy\PyCharmProjects\clixove\venv\lib\site-packages\skopt\space\space.py", line 764, in rvs
    if sp_version < (0, 16):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Version' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: Which `scikit-optimize` version are you using? I have no issue when using the version 0.8

Comment: This should have been a [bug report](https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/issues)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems with scikit-learn >= 0.23 have been fixed in version 0.8.1

Following is the PIP installation:

```
pip install scikit-optimize==0.8.1
```

Reference: [scikit-optimize 0.8.1](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-optimize/0.8.1/)

Answer (score 1):

If scikit-learn version is not important in your problem, you can downgrade scikit-learn version to '0.20.3' by `pip install -U scikit-learn == 0.20.3`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and for your answer. Please consider providing additional reasoning if possible for your answer. This will help you to learn more as well ;) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

I've solved changing skopt/space/space.py lines 763-768

```
 for dim in self.dimensions:
            
            if sp_version < (0, 16):
                columns.append(dim.rvs(n_samples=n_samples))
            else:
                columns.append(dim.rvs(n_samples=n_samples, random_state=rng))
```

into

```
 for dim in self.dimensions:
            
            try:
                columns.append(dim.rvs(n_samples=n_samples, random_state=rng))
            except:
                columns.append(dim.rvs(n_samples=n_samples))
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. It looks like a new change to sci-kit learn changed how versions are read. Checkout the change [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2c0bd624ac6862af35ae9b1af8f3786d538f6b93/sklearn/utils/fixes.py#L28).

If `setuptools` is not installed, `LooseVersion` is used, which returns a `Version` type rather than a tuple.

Does installing `setuptools` in your environment with `pip install setuptools` solve this for you?

Comment: I have the same problem and solved it like IDM. Installing the setuptools explicitly does not help, I just tested it.