# BayesSearchCV TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Version' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, hyperparameters, lightgbm, bayessearchcv

I'm working on the Kaggle Titanic dataset. I'm trying to use LightGBM's LGBMClassifier to determine if a given passenger survived. I've created a pipeline for filling in and processing all of the data and am trying to use BayesSearchCV to optimize my LightGBM hyperparameters. I recieve the following error when I use BayesSearchCV:

"TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Version' and 'tuple'"

I have no idea why I'm getting this error since I can fit the pipleine I created to the data and it works with Sklearn's GridSearchCV so I don't know if this is an issue with BayesSearchCV or it's just me. I've put my pipeline and the code that runs the error below with a mark on where the error occurs.

```
target = 'survived'

categorical_features = ['sex',
                       #'ticket',
                       #'cabin',
                        'embarked']

numeric_features = ['pclass',
                    'age',
                    'sibsp',
                    'parch',
                    'fare']

train, test = train_test_split(df,test_size=0.20)

numerical_pipe = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'mean'))])

categorical_pipe = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'constant', fill_value = 'missing')),
                             ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore'))])

preprocessing = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [
                ('cat', categorical_pipe, categorical_features),
                ('num', numerical_pipe, numeric_features)])

lgb_pipe = Pipeline([
          ('preprocess', preprocessing),
          ('classifier', LGBMClassifier())])

search_space_lgb = {'num_leaves': Integer(1, 500),
                    'max_depth': Integer(1, 500)}

bayes_search_lgb = BayesSearchCV(lgb_pipe, 
                                 search_space_lgb)

bs_lgb = bayes_search_lgb.fit(train[numeric_features + categorical_features], 
                              train[target]) #ERROR HERE

print(bs_lgb.best_params_)
```

This is an extra part of the error I think is useful in identifying what exactly is wrong.

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skopt/space/space.py in rvs(self, n_samples, random_state)

```
762 
763         for dim in self.dimensions:
--> 764             if sp_version < (0, 16):
765                 columns.append(dim.rvs(n_samples=n_samples))
766             else:
```

Found another stackoverflow with the same error as I have ([TypeError inside the `scikit-optimize` package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63353842/typeerror-inside-the-scikit-optimize-package)) but none of the solutions work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The BayesSearchCV come from the skopt library. You don't have to import the whole library you can just type this following command:

from skopt import BayesSearchCV

Also, you might want to use shift+tab to double check on the parameters requirements. Most errors happen at the parameters' level. Let me know if that solve the issue.

Comment: I have only imported BeyesSearchCV from skopt as you reccomended. I double-checked the parameter requirements and it seems they have all been filled. I reduced the code to hopefully narrow in on the problem and will edit the code in the original question to remove any excess noise that isn't causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved changing skopt/space/space.py lines 763-768

```
 for dim in self.dimensions:
        
        if sp_version < (0, 16):
            columns.append(dim.rvs(n_samples=n_samples))
        else:
            columns.append(dim.rvs(n_samples=n_samples, random_state=rng))
```

into

```
for dim in self.dimensions:
        
        try:
            columns.append(dim.rvs(n_samples=n_samples, random_state=rng))
        except:
            columns.append(dim.rvs(n_samples=n_samples))
```